# CSS Rounded borders not applying

Tags: html, css

I'm using Angular and Bootstrap, by the way.

Thing is, I get routed into my template "main.html", it's supposed to apply this style to one of my forms:

```
.main-form{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

But the form is never getting the border rules. It applies both margins, but ignores the rest.

This is my HTML template (as you can see this is for test purposes):

```
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">
    <p ng-bind-html="sideText"></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<span class="label label-info">Sed suscipit dui ac egestas bibendum. </span>
<div class="main-form">
<form>
    <legend>Form title</legend>

    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="">label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Input field">
    </div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Why doesn't it apply the CSS border rules, even if they appear on the Firefox's developer console? Does it have something to do with Angular, or Bootstrap? I guess it shouldn't.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're applying the class to the outer div, not the form - is that by design?

Comment: And if you want uniform rounding you just need it once `border-radius: 13px;` is sufficient and will apply the same 13px to all 4 corners.

Comment: it can come from the bootstrap that you use. can you please look at the inheritence in firebug please?

Comment: There you are not giving border value yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add your class to the form.

```css
.main-form{
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:10px;
  border-radius:13px;
  border:none;
  background:#eee;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="main-form">
    <legend>Form title</legend>

    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="">label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Input field">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**BORDER-RADIUS SUPPORT**

Also border-radius in now strongly supported so it is up to you whether -webkit and -moz is really necessary anymore.

[See browser support list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Comment: That's it. I also just fixed it right now, but you example is better! Thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

because you gives `border: 0px`

```
.main-form{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    border: 10px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: `border` has no effect on `border-radius`. An element can have a radius without a border!

Comment: without **size** how it is possible to give `radius` @Obsidian

Comment: The radius applies to the whole `background`, even if the element has no border. It is the clippiing of the background of the element  and doesn't actually affect the border.

Comment: yaa i accpt but in there code no `background` is given nor `border` given then how `radius` work

Comment: If the `background` is not visible then the `border-radius` effect will also not be visible. So it is the `background` which is essential to see the `border-radius` effect. border-radius is simply the same as cutting the corners of a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-form form {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    border: none;
}
```

- This will apply to the form within the parent div rather than the parent div itself. (without the need to alter any HTML)
- using `border: 0px solid #000000;` doesn't do anything since it's set at 0. If you don't want a border, just use `border: none;` the corners of the div will still be rounded.
- You don't need to use shorthand for all 4 corners of an element unless you want *different* rounding at *specific* corners. If you want them all rounded the same, you just need 1 value for the radius.